# Как правильно дождаться сигнала

Tags: qt5

Из приложения, при вызове одного метода, излучается сигнал. Поток его обрабатывает и излучает сигнал ответа (в произвольный момент времени). Мне необходимо дождаться ответа в ходе выполнения этого метода, а не в слоте прицепленном к сигналу.

Как дождаться прихода сигнала из потока в главном потоке приложения и при этом не "подвесить" главный поток?

Comment: Соединить коннектом, то есть функцией `QObject::connect`

Comment: не того добиваюсь. из приложения, при вызове одного метода, излучается сигнал. поток его обрабатывает и излучает сигнал ответа. мне необходимо дождаться ответа в ходе выполнения этого метода, а не в слоте прицепленном к сигналу. отсюда и вопрос....

Comment: Но, если рассуждать логически, если вы останавливаете выполнение метода из которого излучили сигнал, то вы останавливаете выполнение потока в котором этот метод находится, до получения ответа. Ведь так? Если метод находится в главном потоке приложения, то вы останавливаете само приложение. Надо больше информации в вопросе - может быть вам надо архитектуру подправить

Comment: По-факту фоновая работа потока здесь и не нужна, потому что вы все равно хотите остановить метод вызова до получения ответа из потока. А если все же поток нужен, то надо смотреть на архитектуру

Comment: согласен. тут скорей архитектурные проблемы. Хорошо. Почешем РЭПУ :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо использовать QEventLoop
Например так:

```
QEventLoop loop;
connect(&parser, SIGNAL(answer_received()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
this.sendQuery();
loop.exec();
```

Comment: ок. гляну Ваш вариант. Спасибо